# Must a new line follow the XML declaration?

Tags: xml

Is this one a valid XML instance? It has nothing between the the XML declaration and the root node.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><data></data>
```

I could not find the right place in the XML specification myself and hope that somebody will help me...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The spec (see [*2.8 Prolog and Document Type Declaration*](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-prolog-dtd)) does not require (but does allow) a newline to follow the XML Declaration.

Formally this is written as:

> `[16]         PI         ::=      '<?' PITarget (S (Char* - (Char* '?>' Char*)))? '?>'`
>   ...
>   `[22]         prolog     ::=       XMLDecl? Misc* (doctypedecl Misc*)?`
>   `[23]         XMLDecl    ::=      '<?xml' VersionInfo EncodingDecl? SDDecl? S? '?>'`
>   ...
>   `[27]         Misc       ::=       Comment | PI | S`

As you can see in `[22] prolog` the XML Declaration is *optional* (see the questionark after the symbol) and zero, one or more (see the star) `Misc` can follow which are: Comments, other Processing Instructions (`PI`) or Whitespace (`S`). Whitespace includes the newline.

Because `Misc` is optional here, there can but need not follow a newline after the declaration.

Comment: But probably somewhere else in the specification there is a statement?

Comment: Then the spec would contradict itself.

Comment: But probably the spec says something about how the document content must begin?

Comment: Yes, that's what "the following section about prolog" is about: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-prolog-dtd (the one with [22] and [23])

Answer (score 2):

New lines or so are not part of the spec. When you, for example, write a XML Document with the XMLOutputter Class (in Java), you get a file without newlines. Newlines are for humans.

Comment: Thank you. But I cannot be sure only because some Java implementations do this.