# Remove white space between xmldocument and root node in libxml2 c

Tags: c, xml, libxml2

I have created a xml tree using libxml2 C. For example, my output is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`  

<Ocean>                                 

    <Sea>Pacific</Sea>

    <Lake>Tahoe</Lake>

</Ocean>
```

I have used `xmlDocDumpMemoryEnc(....)` to remove node indenting and then my output is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Ocean><Sea>Pacific</Sea><Lake>Tahoe</Lake></Ocean>
```

However I want my output as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Ocean><Sea>Pacific</Sea><Lake>Tahoe</Lake></Ocean>
```

I have searched libxml2 module functions to remove white space between xmldocument and root node and found none. I greatly appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While [not mandated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8384559/must-a-new-line-follow-the-xml-declaration) by the standard, it's common to have a new line after the XML declaration.

libxml2 has this new line [hardcoded](https://github.com/GNOME/libxml2/blob/d77e5fc4bcdb7da748c9cca116a601ae4df60d21/xmlsave.c#L1210), so you are left with either, having libxml2 skip the XML declaration and prepending it yourself or output it and [shifting](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memmove) it right to overwrite the line break.

Comment: Or if it's the new line specifically and not the whitespace that bothers you, replace the line feed with a space character.